# Azure Automation modules do not update to latest version

Tags: powershell, module, updates, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I'm trying to update Azure Automation modules using Azure web interface.
Script `Update-AutomationAzureModulesForAccount` runs without errors, but modules do not update to latest version. For example, `AzureRM.profile` updates to 4.2.0, while the latest one is 4.3.0.
Update also not happen if I choose to install `AzureRM.profile` 4.3.0 from modules gallery, and check 'Update nessesary modules' option.
What can be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Automation is currently having problems with the latest module versions on PS Gallery. Because of this, `Update-AutomationAzureModulesForAccount` is temporarily redirected to the last known good versions instead of the latest versoins. We expect to resolve this issue within the next few days.

This restriction is applied to the Update Azure Modules button and the `Update-AutomationAzureModulesForAccount` runbook only. So, if you import a module using any other means, there is no restriction. For example, if you select a specific module version on https://www.powershellgallery.com/ and push the Deploy to Azure Automation button, this is the version that will be deployed to Azure Automation. However, unless you have a strong reason to use the latest versions right now, I would recommend relying on the Update Azure Modules button and the `Update-AutomationAzureModulesForAccount` runbook.

Comment: This is fixed now. The Update Azure Modules button in the Automation portal will install the latest module versions from the PS Gallery, including the fixed AzureRM.Profile 4.3.1. Please don’t try to import AzureRM.Profile 4.3.0 into your Automation account. Thank you for your patience.